# SharePoint 2013 AppFabric Installer Skipped

Tags: installation, app-fabric

Trying to install SharePoint 2013 in *VirtualBox* and for some reason the *AppFabric* installation is always skipped. All other prerequisites have been installed.

I referenced the following post: [SharePoint 2013 AppFabric Installation Error 3](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112169/sharepoint-2013-appfabric-installation-error) and used that same line of code in the command prompt. I also placed the `AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe` file in the `prerequisiteinstallerfiles` folder. The Preparation Tool runs fine but when it completes it always says the AppFabric installation was skipped:

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is and how it can be corrected so I can install SharePoint? Windows Server 2012 as well as SQL Server 2012 are installed on a virtual machine in VirtualBox and i'm trying to install SharePoint 2013 on the same device for testing purposes as I'm new to Sharepoint.